# Track embedded youtube videos with Universal Analytics

Tags: youtube, analytics, tracking, universal

I am upgrading to Universal Analytics and was hoping to track youtube videos embedded in my tumblr blog. Can anyone help me adapt the following code to work with Universal Analytics?

---

```
<script>
  // This code loads the IFrame Player API code asynchronously.
  var tag = document.createElement('script');
  tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
  var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
  firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);

  //  This function creates an <iframe> (and YouTube player)
  //    after the API code downloads.
  var player;
  function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
    player = new YT.Player('player', {
      height: '289',
      width: '428',
      videoId: 'VIDEO ID',
      events: {
        'onReady': onPlayerReady,
        'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
      }
    });
  }
  //  The API will call this function when the video player is ready. Uncomment the below code to start video when ready
  function onPlayerReady(event) {
    // event.target.playVideo();
    }
  function onPlayerStateChange(event) {
    var lastAction="";
      switch (event.data){
        case YT.PlayerState.PLAYING:
        if (lastAction != 'paused'){
            _gaq.push(['_trackEvent','video', 'Playing', getPercentage()]);
        }
        else{
            lastAction = '';
           }
        break;
        case YT.PlayerState.ENDED:
          _gaq.push(['_trackEvent','video', 'Completed',getPercentage()]);
        break;
        case YT.PlayerState.PAUSED:
         if (lastAction != 'paused'){
            _gaq.push(['_trackEvent','video', 'Paused', getPercentage()]);
            lastAction= "paused";
           }
        break;
        }
    }
    function getPercentage()
    {
    var pecentage =((player.getCurrentTime()/player.getDuration())*100).toFixed();
      if(pecentage > 0 && pecentage <= 25){
       return "0-25%";}
      elseif(pecentage > 25 && pecentage <= 50){
       return "25-50%";}
      elseif(pecentage > 50 && pecentage <= 75){
       return "50-75%";}
      elseif(pecentage > 75){
       return "75-100%";}
    }
    function stopVideo() {
     _gaq.push(['_trackEvent','video', 'Stopped', player.getDuration()]);
      player.stopVideo();
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Did this work for you on the old analytics? I'm trying to do this right now but don't have anything as a starting point. If this worked then it might just be changing `_gaq.push...` to the new `ga('send'...` via https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/upgrade/reference/gajs-analyticsjs

Answer (score 3):

I tried straight with your code and had some problems but just got it working at least for basic notification when played / finished using this code:

```
<div id="player"></div>

<script>
  // 2. This code loads the IFrame Player API code asynchronously.
  var tag = document.createElement('script');

  tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
  var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
  firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);

  // 3. This function creates an <iframe> (and YouTube player)
  //    after the API code downloads.
  var player;
  function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
    player = new YT.Player('player', {
      height: '360',
      width: '640',
      videoId: 'VIDEOID HERE',
      events: {
        'onReady': onPlayerReady,
        'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
      }
    });
  }

  // 4. The API will call this function when the video player is ready.
  //    Uncomment the event to have video start automatically.
  function onPlayerReady(event) {
    // event.target.playVideo();
  }

  // 5. The API calls this function when the player's state changes.
  //    The function indicates that when playing a video,
  //    the player should send to Google Analytics.
  function onPlayerStateChange(event) {
    if (event.data == YT.PlayerState.PLAYING) {
      ga('send', 'event', 'YouTube', 'Watched', 'Promo from Main Page');
    }
    if (event.data == YT.PlayerState.ENDED) {
      ga('send', 'event', 'YouTube', 'Finished', 'Promo from Main Page');
    }
  }
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply Ryan. While understanding whether the video is played or stopped is useful, what would be really useful is understanding the duration played (in 25% increments).

Any suggestions on how to code for that in UA?

Comment: @Art did you try to use your code combined with mine (or the Google link I left in comments)?

Comment: Am planning on testing this weekend. Work has been crazy and I haven't been able to try it out. Will ping you with the results when finished. Thanks man!

Comment: @Art I might do more on it now as well, I was at a trade show last week and didn't have time to tinker with it more

Comment: Good stuff @Ryan and thanks a million.. The other main point of interest, as I mentioned before, is understanding play duration (25% increments work)

Comment: your code works brilliantly! If there's anyway you can help me figure out how to measure play duration, that would rock!